# tag for random number generators

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Many people come here asking about something related to a hardware random number generator (HRNG), sometimes called "a true random number generator".

A few people post questions related to pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), often a linear-feedback shift register (LFSR) [(a)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/55704/how-are-lfsrs-used-in-real-applications-as-prngs).

What is a good tag for questions about HRNG, PRNG, or LFSR?

Currently some questions about generating random numbers [(b)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/460/is-arduino-ideal-for-making-a-hrng-hardware-random-number-generator) use the "[generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/generator)" tag, or the "[function-generator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/function-generator)" tag.
Should we mention in the tag description that the tag also applies to random number generators, or is there a better tag that we could use?

If no good tag exists yet for these kinds of questions, I propose a "[random-number](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/random-number)" tag to cover both HRNG and PRNG.

Comment: "random number" is clear, concise and not encumbered with domain specific language that a neophyte would not be able to find like LFSR.

Comment: @rawbrawb but HRNG could have a tag  explaining it and hardwareRandom or some such as a synonym.

Comment: Sounds like you write up an answer ...  ;)

Answer (score 7):

I second the "random-number" tag proposition. It will be obvious that it's about generating them.

I think that the "generator" and "function-generator" tags you mention should be removed those questions. "Generator" refers to generating electric power, and "function-generator" generates electrical signals.